# Finding an homotopy from $SX \to SX$

Tags: algebraic-topology

In order to prove (using the Steenrod-Eilenberg axioms) that $$ \tilde{E}_k(SX) \cong  \tilde{E}_k(\Sigma X)$$ where $S$ denotes the unreduced suspension and $\Sigma$ the reduced one, during lectures we wrote the following chain of isomorphisms
$$\tilde{E}_k(SX) \cong E_k(SX, (*,0)) \cong E_k(SX, \{*\}\times I) \cong \tilde{E}_k(\Sigma X)$$

Where we assumed that $*$ in $X$ has a def. retract neighbourhood.

I've problem in proving the second isomorphism, because I don't know how to find an homotopy of $SX$ in itself which restricted to $\{*\}\times I$ is an homotopy to the point $(*,0)$. My guess this is the way to proceed, because even the lecturer gives as explanation the homotopy between the two spaces without writing it explicitly or giving some hints about how to find it.

Can someone provide me some hints on how ton find such homotopy? Or there is another way to solve it?

Comment: Let $U$ be the deformation retract neighborhood of $*$.  Then $U\times I$ is a deformation retract neighborhood of $\{*\}\times I$.

Comment: Mmh ok, but how does this help for the homotopy of the second iso? (I'll use such argument to obtain the third iso btw)

Comment: You can use the deformation retract to form a map $(SX,\{*\}\times I)\rightarrow (SX,(*,0))$ that induces an isomorphism on homology.

Comment: actually I thought about it, but I didn't found any way to extend such an homotopy to all of $SX$. Are there some tricks to do that?

Comment: Sorry.  What I said above may not be the best route.  A better idea is that you have the inclusion map $(SX,(*,))\rightarrow (SX,\{*\}\times I)$.  Since there is a neighborhood of $\{*\}\times I$ that deformation retracts to $(*,0)$, the inclusion is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Ok, informally I'm following your reasoning and this makes sense, but I cannot write down explicitly the map (or find an argument to support it). We have the inclusion (which is the identity because it is the inclusion from a space to itself right?). Then the idea should be to use the retraction to define the "homotpy inverse" of this map. But I need to extend the retraction to all SX, and I don't know how to do it. I don't see any other way of using your hints :( (and thanks for helping me!!)

Answer (score 1):

It follows by excision.  You have a pushout square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(*,0) @>>> \{*\}\times I \\
@VVV @VVV \\
SX @>>> SX
\end{CD}
$$
So, excision says that $\tilde{E}(SX,(*,0)\cong \tilde{E}(SX,\{*\}\times I)$.

EDIT: You can phrase excision as saying that a pushout square 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A @>>> B \\
@VVV @VVV \\
X @>>> Y
\end{CD}
$$
gives an isomorphism in homology $E_n(X,A)\cong E_n(Y,B)$.  To relate this to the usual statement of excision, we have a pushout square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
A\cap B @>>> B \\
@VVV @VVV \\
A @>>> X
\end{CD}
$$
So, $E_n(X,B)\cong E_n(A,A\cap B)$.

Comment: Well it seems a neat solution, but I didn't covered any relation between push out and excision, can you give me some reference about where to look in order to chatch up and understand your answer?

Comment: @LuigiM I posted a little more.